# Books/Resources on generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions

I'm currently doing a research on generating functions, but I have only found few books on this topic. Can anyone provide references (if possible, trying to assess the level of math competence required) on generating functions?

Ideally, what is the context of the referenced book and further details to help to put the book itself in context would be much appreciated.

Comment: [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf)

Comment: Be also aware that generating function is very related to the Z-transform (much used in discrete signal processing)

Comment: More advanced: "Combinatorial Species and Tree-like Structures" by Bergeron, Labelle, Leroux

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The second edition of Herbert Wilf’s *generatingfunctionology* is freely available [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) in PDF form. [*Concrete Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025), by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, has a very nice introduction in Chapter $7$ and is a very fine book all around.

Answer (score 18):

Look into [***generatingfunctionology***](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) by Herbert S. Wilf.

It's precisely about *generating functions*! Fairly short but thorough.  From the link (Wilf's website), you can

- download the $2$nd edition of the text (as a pdf document),
- download a version of the book with hyperlinks to be read on-line,
- or else click on the link to the publisher if you'd like to purchase the $3$rd edition.
- (Perhaps you can obtain a hard copy from you library.)

---

From MIT (and a course taught there), you can download a pdf dedicated to ***[generating functions](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/fall05/ln11.pdf)***, which is outlined nicely, and allows you to access the topics in order, or those of interest.

---

Finally, see Ch. 10: [***Generating Functions***](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter10.pdf) of the freely available text authored by Grinstead and Laurie Snell, and published by the AMS: [***Introduction to Probability***](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/book.html).

---

You might want to invest in [***Concrete Mathematics***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025) by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik. It has a nicely written introduction to generating functions,

Comment: Sadly, the link from MIT is no more accessible for public. You have to get a permission to access it.

Comment: But it's an informative recommendations as always :)

Answer (score 15):

Another great freely (and legally!) available online resource is Flajolet and Sedgewick's [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html), which in addition to having lots of material about generating functions also has lots of material about asymptotic analysis.

Comment: It’s at a higher level than Wilf’s book, which in turn is at a higher level than *Concrete Mathematics*, but I second this recommendation.

Answer (score 13):

*Concrete Mathematics* by Knuth, Graham, and Patashnik.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the titles in other answers you can check Sergei Lando's book [Lectures on Generating Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821834819)

Answer (score 2):

The book "A = B" which is freely downloadable at http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html.

Comment: the book cannot be downloaded?

Comment: Downloading worked for me.

Comment: Is there an errata list?

Comment: no errata of which i am aware at this time.  Also think he gives too much impetus on Maple and Mathematica particulars for his different subjects and chapters without real explaining of how Maple or Mathematica derived their own routines so one is sort of left in the dark on these points which seems to me to be of not much if any real relevance or knowledge to be gained or little if any real useful information for the reader.

Comment: Unless the reader is specifically interested in using mathematica or Maple in which case routines are explained somewhat in appendix of book A=B.

Answer (score 1):

George Andrew's book [The Theory of Partitions](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511608650) uses generating functions a lot. The book also discusses restricted and other types of partitions which require ever more interesting types of generating functions. This may help in understanding some applications of generating functions.

Answer (score 0):

and of course the familiar ' The art of computer programming ' volume I Fundamental Algorithms by Donald Knuth beginning p87 and esp the exercises beginning p94 which in my opinion has too many thereof and realistically are not going to have time to do most of them yourself so just use his answers to those exercises beginning p496 mainly as continuation of part of his teaching tools on the subject.

Also the text by Manuel Kauers . Peter Paule
The Concrete Tetrahedron
about Symbolic Sums, Recurrence Equations,
Generating Functions, Asymptotic Estimates
SpringerWienNewYork which is quite interesting

Answer (score 0):

Chattamvelli and Shanmugam's *Generating functions in engineering and the applied sciences*, published by Morgan and Claypool in 2019 is a good start for anyone interested in applications of GF.